# IIS site returns a 403 response on every page for certain browsers (by user agent string)

Tags: iis, web-config, http-status-code-403

I have a Wordpress site running on IIS site which returns a hard 403 response for certain user agent strings (IE 6 - 10 and Firefox 33 Mac and Win). After some poking around by manually changing the user agent string I determined that the strings `Trident/4` , `Trident/5` , and `Firefox/3` all cause this site to exhibit this behavior. There might be other combinations, but clearly this is something going on in either the code or the IIS level.

I've scanned the code at a high level and found some mentions of both Firefox and Trident, all related to user agent sniffing, but they appear to be core Wordpress files and not app specific code. I've been searching all afternoon and the only things I find mention of are telling the user to adjust the "directory browsing" settings in web.config. However I can replicate the behavior by directly accessing a static asset such as a CSS file. That tells me not only is it not related to directory browsing, but it's probably also not anything to do with application code.

Can anyone offer insight into what might be happening here? To head off questions:

1. We just noticed this behavior a few weeks ago, unsure of how long it's been going on.
2. I'll be checking access/error logs as soon as I can get them.

EDIT

Turns out that the previous developers had added some very specific URL rewriting rules for the site. They were explicitly returning a 403 for any user agent with the patterns I listed above, along with a few other generic patterns and some specific botnames. I *knew* it had to be something with the web server...we just had to poke around in IIS long enough to find them.

Comment: What's the substatus code of 403 error and exception code? Please enable failed request tracing to trace the 403 error. It will at least tell us which side returned the 403 response. It is appreciated if you could post more information in failed request tracing log. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Today I'm working to get access to web logs, which should give me more info about the error. Will come back to this post as soon as I've got more to share.

Comment: Hi. Have you fixed it by handling these rewrite rule?

Comment: Hey Jokies, we fixed it by removing/editing those rules.